# Скрывать контент на jquery

Tags: jquery

Привет, знатоки.

Верстаю сейчас каталог товаров с достаточно витиеватой системой разделов и подразделов и столкнулся с такой задачкой.

Есть список разделов с подразделами. Этих подразделов может быть сколько угодно, а может и совсем не быть. Так вот надо как-то ограничить количество показываемых подразделов.

Поясню. Если количество подразделов умещается в 2 строчки, то все ок, а если нет, то что не влезло нужно скрыть и в конце добавить ссылку "еще". Вот как-то так.

Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

для ul задайте overflow: hidden

Comment: оно-то понятно, что overflow: hidden спрячет то что не влезло, но как добавить/удалить ссыль "еще" если не влезло/влезло... основной вопрос как раз в этом

Answer (score 0):

Что-то вроде этого, вот пример [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sZLSD/1)

```
var i = 0;

$( "li" ).each(function() {
  i++;
    if(i > 2){
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
if(i > 2){
  $("<li><a href='#'>Еще</a></li>").appendTo($("ul"));
}
```

Comment: Не совсем то... я, видимо, объяснил не совсем точно.
Вот этих самых <li> может быть сколько угодно и вытягиваются они на всю ширину блока в строчку.

Высота блока 2 строки. Вот именно если в эти 2 строки количество <li> не умещается, тогда и должна добавляться ссылка "еще". Вот как-то так http://jsfiddle.net/3gSp7/1/

Все что выходит за границы блока должно прятаться за ссылкой еще

Comment: @fenris, может проще так: http://jsfiddle.net/3gSp7/2/ ?

Comment: Проще-то оно конечно проще, вот только надо именно добавлять ссылку "Еще" и разворачивать по клику.